# Search information based on sound from microphone

Tags: java, audio, speech-recognition, microphone

can you please tell me that ...Is it possible to search words that are in database and list them,when using spell the words through the microphone in swing?if possible how can i implement this one.thanks in advance

Comment: The search term you need is 'speech recognition'.  I added the tag.

Comment: If your question is whether Swing provides that feature, then the answer is "no, not by a long shot". Swing has nothing to do with the solution to your problem.

Comment: See also SO for [tags speech-recognition+Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition+java).

Answer (score 0):

A little googling returned allot of results ... just search for "java speech recognition API "

I think the easiest approach would be this : [voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/)

Anyways , whatever API you decide to use , SWING has nothing to do with it , it's just a UI manager (not sure about terminology here ) , you will have to build the interface yourself , add the proper action listeners and put the speech recognition stuff in there ...

and btw we would be able to help you out more once you tried some and edited your post after with what you tried .